# Unity3d: Find which gameObject is in front

Tags: unity, mathematics, rotation, vector, direction

I have two `gameObjects` `A` and `B`. They are `rotated` at `90 degrees`, which makes its `local y axis` face forward.

**1st Case**

[image]

In this case, the `local y position of B` is ahead of `local y position of A`

**2nd Case**

[image]

Even though their global position is same as the 1st case, we can observe here that `local y position of A` is ahead of `local y position of B`.

I tried using `A.transform.localPosition.y` and `B.transform.localPosition.y` to find which is greater but it doesnt work. What can I do to find which is front in these two different cases?

Comment: What are you after exaclty? In front, but with regards to what?

Comment: It's based on perspective and direction

Comment: In 1st case, Imagine they are running straight, and in 2nd case, they are running at the left direction. The global postions are same in borh cases, but in 1st case B is ahead and in 2nd case, A is ahead

Comment: Yes, and so you want to find out which one is ahead of the other, assuming they'll always be facing the same direction and turning at the same time?

Comment: Yeah exactly!!!

Comment: Are you SURE that A and B will always have the same rotation as each other? 
I can imagine someone trying to implement a racetrack asking this question, for example, and in that case the cars might be facing different angles at different times...

Comment: @AC Yeah Thanks, it would be better to consider different angles as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check simple ahead/behind relationships using [the dot product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product):

```
Vector3 displacement = B.transform.position - A.transform.position;

float dot = Vector3.Dot(displacement, A.transform.forward);
```

If `dot` is greater than zero, then B is ahead of A along A's forward vector. (The arrow from A to B has a component in the same direction as A's forward)

If `dot` is less than zero, then B is behind A along A's forward vector. (The arrow from A to B has a component in the opposite direction as A's forward)

If `dot` is zero, then B is somewhere directly to the side of A, neither in front nor behind. The A→B arrow points perpendicular to A's forward axis.

Comment: FWIW, this approach will work even if B is in a different orientation from A -- it will just tell you whether B is in front or behind A, relative to A's orientation.  N.B. that if the two orientations *are* different, then it is possible for A to be ahead of B along A's path, and B to be simultaneously ahead of A on B's path.